# rest end points in controller classes of spring boot are not exposed when deployed in google cloud

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform

when spring boot rest service deployed in google cloud and try to access the get or post end points i am getting not found error. but it works fine in local and also when i moved the end points from controller classes to main class then i am able to access the end points from google cloud.

Structrue:

[image]

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.stocklookup</groupId>
  <artifactId>TheStockLookUP</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <name>TheStocker</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.8</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <version>1</version>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <source>8</source>
            <target>8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

TheStockMainApp:

[image]

i have deployed the code in app engine standard env.

Comment: Have you checked this? : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning

Comment: yes tried the component scan even though its working in local but still its not working in the  google cloud